# Почему не работает Process.Start() в AvaloniaUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, процесс, avalonia

Пробовал по разному, но выходит одно и тоже.
При любом способе запуска `Process.Start` в `AvaloniaUI` ничего не происходит.

Вот мои попытки:

```
Process.Start("calc.exe"); ///Ничего не происходит

Task.Run(() => Process.Start("calc.exe")); ///так же
```

Но когда вызывается в консольном, `WPF` и `WinForms` программе, все работает.

Кстати, в предпросмотре `UI` в дизайнере, все процессы запускаются, даже по нескольку раз при изменении `XAML`.

[image: На этом фото запустился калькулятор, при внесении правки в XAML разметку]

Файл проекта:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <!--Avalonia doesen't support TrimMode=link currently,but we are working on that https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/6892 -->
    <TrimMode>copyused</TrimMode>
    <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove=".gitignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!--This helps with theme dll-s trimming.
    If you will publish your application in self-contained mode with p:PublishTrimmed=true and it will use Fluent theme Default theme will be trimmed from the output and vice versa.
    https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5593 -->
    <TrimmableAssembly Include="Avalonia.Themes.Fluent" />
    <TrimmableAssembly Include="Avalonia.Themes.Default" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia" Version="0.10.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Desktop" Version="0.10.18" />
    <!--Condition below is needed to remove Avalonia.Diagnostics package from build output in Release configuration.-->
    <PackageReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Include="Avalonia.Diagnostics" Version="0.10.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="XamlNameReferenceGenerator" Version="1.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Как решить проблему, может кто знает?

Comment: Это надолго....

Comment: Версия дотнета в консоли и в авалонии одинаковая?

Comment: Для какой платформы вы проект собираете? Приведите ваш файл проекта, чтобы нам не приходилось гадать.

Comment: @aepot dotnet одинаковый, .NET 6, но в Авалонии независимо от версии Process.Start не работает

Comment: @PavelMayorov winexe, .net 6.0, Avalonia 0.10.18
Независимо от версии .NET, процессы не запускаются

Comment: Попробуйте `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("calc.exe") { UseShellExecute = true });`

Comment: @aepot Все сработало, спасибо
Хорошо, как теперь мне закрыть данный вопрос?

Comment: Не надо закрывать, нормальный вопрос, можете сами оформить ответ и закрепить галочкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ответ из комментариев(рабочий):

##### Задать параметр `UseShellExecute = true;`

Пример:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("calc.exe") { UseShellExecute = true });
```